# Adding play/pause funkionality to icon in Elementor FREE

Tags: html, css, wordpress, audio, elementor

I am trying to implement play/pause funktionality to 3 icons on a WordPress website that uses Elementor.
I have followed this guide: https://urielsoto.com/play-audio-on-click-using-elementor/

Which led me to 3 seperate HTML-Code Elements beneath each of the 3 icons looking like the following, with the only exection that i changed "audioButton1", "audio-button1" and "audio1" to 2 and 3 respectively:

```
<script>
let audioButton1 = document.querySelector('.audio-button1');   // <-- Change CSS Class Here
       audioButton1.addEventListener('click', function(){
        var audio1 = document.getElementById("audio1");

         if (audio1.paused) {
            audio1.play();
        }else{
            audio1.pause();
            // audio1.currentTime = 0
        }
      });
</script>

    <audio id="audio1" src="http://...(privacy).com"></audio>
```

All three buttons working seperately, doing their thing, wonderful!

To make them real audio play buttons though, once clicked the icon should show a pause icon as an indication of a running soundclip.
There is a follow up tutorial on how to do this but unfortunately with the free version of Elementor I am not able to add custom CSS to the icon: https://urielsoto.com/toggle-between-icons-and-images-on-click-with-elementor/

I have added the folowing lines to my code:

```
audioButton1.addEventListener('click', function(){
audioButton1.classList.toggle('toggle-pause');
});
```

Making this my final HTML-Code:

```
<script>
let audioButton1 = document.querySelector('.audio-button1');   // <-- Change CSS Class Here
       audioButton1.addEventListener('click', function(){
        var audio1 = document.getElementById("audio1");

         if (audio1.paused) {
            audio1.play();
        }else{
            audio1.pause();
            // audio1.currentTime = 0
        }
  
audioButton1.addEventListener('click', function(){
audioButton1.classList.toggle('toggle-pause');

      });
</script>

    <audio id="audio1" src="http://...(privacy).com"></audio>
```

The following is the (from my understanding) necessary CSS-Code for this to work:

```
.toggle-pause .elementor-icon i::before{
    content: '\f04c';
}
```

Since I can not add the CSS via Elementor, my thought was to just add it in the HTML, but unfortunately my skills more or less end here.

I have looked up how to implement CSS into HTML and came across this:

```
// One liner function:
const addCSS = css => document.head.appendChild(document.createElement("style")).innerHTML=css;

// Usage: 
addCSS("body{ background:red; }")
```

If i add my CSS it looks like this:

```
// One liner function:
const addCSS = css => document.head.appendChild(document.createElement("style")).innerHTML=css;

// Usage: 
addCSS(".toggle-pause .elementor-icon i::before{
    content: '\f04c';")
```

Since im a complete noob, i have no idea if this is a right direction or not. I have tried putting it all together in all sorts of ways but i feel like there is more to it than this. Any help gladly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok I gave ChatGPT a shot and got an answer pretty fast: combined code is as follows
Workes great:

```
<script>
  let audioButton1 = document.querySelector('.audio-button1');
  audioButton1.addEventListener('click', function () {
    var audio1 = document.getElementById("audio1");

    if (audio1.paused) {
      audio1.play();
    } else {
      audio1.pause();
      // audio1.currentTime = 0
    }

    audioButton1.classList.toggle('toggle-pause');
  });
</script>

<style>
  .toggle-pause .elementor-icon i::before {
    content: '\f04c';
  }
</style>

<audio id="audio1" src="http://...(privacy).com"></audio>
```